# /bin/sh -l -c 'command' does not load profile

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I'm trying to execute a command ensuring the login profile is loaded beforehand.

My approach from my application is to execute `/bin/sh -l -c 'command' arg1 arg2 ...`.

However, `/bin/sh -l -c` doesn't seem to execute the profile.

I've narrowed it down to putting `export PROFILE_LOADED='true'` in `~/.profile` and executing `/bin/sh -l -c 'echo "$PROFILE_LOADED"`.

This doesn't seem to work on macOS, but possibly works on Ubuntu18.04.

Is there a way to accomplish this in general with a command passed to `-c` across Unix-like platforms?

Comment: Similar: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208408/profile-is-not-loaded-on-non-login-bin-sh

Comment: It works if you use `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`

Comment: MacOS is running an older version of `bash`, it looks like they "fixed" this in newer versions, which are used in Linux.